# How does the EnsureAuthenticated in the TFS API Work?

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm working on a web application that works with the TFS API and I would like to make sure that any users that use it have the proper authentication to use TFS.

To do so I use the following code:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = configServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);
teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated;
```

I'm going to host the website on IIS.

When a user uses the web app, will EnsureAuthenticated use their credentials, or will it use the credentials of the remote desktop I'm hosting the application on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If you have configured ASP.NEt to use impersonation, it will use the account of the logged user.

If ASP.NET is configured with default settings there are a number of things that can happen

- If there is a credential stored in the Credentials Manager it will use that
- If the application pool is running under a real account it will try to do that
- If the application pool is running an application pool account, it will probably try to authenticate with the System's account (COMPUTER$)

I'd say, try it and look at the IIS logs of your TFS server or use something like fiddler to capture the traffic.